# Public read only Splunk data for testing

Tags: testing, splunk

Is there a public instance of Splunk that can be used to test queries?

I Googled "public splunk test instance" and didn't see anything there.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no publicly available Splunk.
However, Splunk is free to download and install on your laptop so there's always an instance available for you to test with.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Splunk cloud trial from https://www.splunk.com/page/sign_up/cloud_trial

But as Rich G said, it's free to install and run yourself